Is there a library for Semitic Roots and their meanings?
I am trying to create new custom words in Arabic using its verbforms and Semetic root framework and it has been going quite well. I have found an Arabic-Roman transliterator and a list of all verbforms (including their verbal nouns, active participles, and passive participles) but finding Semitic roots has been difficult.
Currently, my method is google translating an English word into Arabic, plugging that word into wiktionary, and then accessing the specific page for the Semitic root that wiktionary has identified for it, where it usually shows what sort of words the root pertains too.
What I would love is if there was a library of the Semitic roots that shows they pertain too so that as a writer I could use the library to think of new words without building upon the potential mistranslations of my current method.

There are Arabic dictionaries organised by the roots (e.g., Hans Wehr's dictionary). Afaik, those dictionaries are still only available in their printed editions, I am not aware of electronic versions of them.

“… so that as a writer I could use the library to think of new words without building upon the potential mistranslations of my current method“ — I don’t see how using a root list would alleviate this problem. It’s always going to be dangerous using words that you don’t know how they’re normally used.

I agree with Keelan's comment that using a library of roots is unlikely to alleviate your issues of producing mistranslations.
That notwithstanding, there is the Semitic Roots Repository. It's volunteer maintained, and not affiliated with any institution, but is generally accurate and reasonably comprehensive. For many entries it also lets you view the sense of the root in each language it's attested in, as the sense can shift dramatically from the reconstructed one.
